# Embedded video in Facebook timeline shows "download link", won't play inline only when shared through facebook open graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here are the og meta tags I'm using:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://videogami.s3.amazonaws.com/54c2c58c19d5bdec65000036.mp4"> 
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://videogami.s3.amazonaws.com/54c2c58c19d5bdec65000036.mp4"> 
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"> 
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="600"> 
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="380">
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://videogami.s3.amazonaws.com/54c2c58c19d5bdec65000036.big.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://videogami.tv/h/54c2c58c19d5bdec65000036" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
```

If I share the link manually, the embedding works perfectly. But when I share the link through the Facebook /me/feed api, it won't play and just shows a link to the mp4 that says "download file".

Here is an example link: http://videogami.tv/h/54c2bb1719d5bdec65000030

Any idea why this might be happening? I'm pretty sure you don't need a flash player anymore, it said nothing about this in the FB docs that I could find.

It makes no sense that it would work when you manually post it, vs posting the link through the api...

[image: before playing]
[image: after clicking play]

Comment: By the way, I never figured this out... It seemed to fix itself after a while.

Comment: Any precision about the time it requires to "fix itself"?

Comment: @dirtv it was fixed the next day (24 hours)

Comment: Okay, well for me it still doesn't show up.
I only provided the html5 video, so it might be because of that...